# How to validate certain input parameters through a Validation API?

Tags: java, validation, apache-commons

I have an API in which I am doing my own validation for certain input parameters. For example -

```
    public Builder(int clientId) {
        TestUtils.assertNonNegative(clientId, "ClientId");
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

    public Builder setUserId(String userid) {
        TestUtils.assertNotNull(userid, "UserId");
        this.userid = userid;
        return this;
    }
```

And my `assertNonNegative` and `assertNotNull` method in `TestUtils` class is like this -

```
public static void assertNonNegative(int val, String attr) {
    if (val <= 0) {
        s_logger.logError("Attribute = ", attr, " Value = ", val, " error=", attr, " cannot be negative or zero");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(attr + " cannot be negative or zero");
    }
}

public static void assertNotNull(String value, String key) {
    if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
        s_logger.logError("Key = ", key, " Value = ", value, " error=", key,
                " cannot be NULL or empty String");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(key + " cannot be null OR empty");
    }
}
```

I am wondering is there any validation API available in any open source projects which I can use to substitute the above internal method I have? If yes, can anyone provide an example how would I achieve this? I still need to throw the same message back as an IllegalArgumentException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand why would you use an external API tu achieve a nullOrEmpty or a non-negative number validation but...

If you would like to verifiy an id of a user in a database directly in you Java app

This might interest you to learn:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Use a bit of PHP and verify if the user is in the database.

```
if(isset($_GET['idcmd']))
{
    switch($_GET['idcmd'])
    {
        case 1:
                if(isset($_POST['iduser']))
                {
                    $sql= "SELECT idUser FROM users WHERE idUser=:iduser ";
                    $result = $db_conn->prepare($sql);
                    $result->bindParam(":iduser" ,$_POST['iduser']);
                    $result->execute();

                    $num=$result->fetchColumn();
                    if($num > 0){
                        echo "cool";
                    }else{
                        echo "nocool";
                    }
                }
        break;
    }
}
```

Now if you make a POST request to the url www.mydomain.com/myapi.php?idcmd=1 and get the response cool, it means that the user is in database.

I hope it helps.